# アプリの審査についてOn cellular networkとは？

Tags: ios

アプリの審査で却下された理由の部分に
On cellular network　とありました。
これってどのような状況なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

電話回線=3GやLTEでの接続時に問題があるよ、という意味です。

おそらく他にも却下された理由が記載されているはずで、それが電話回線での接続時に発生しますよ、という意味だと考えられます。

より詳しく知りたい場合は、そのメッセージの全文を転載されたほうが良いです。